# Destructor causing runtime error

Tags: c++, c++11, tree, runtime-error

I am working with Trees, for practice purpose. Precisely Binary Search Trees currently. I have a general `Tree` class which I use to solve the BST problems.
So, I come across a problem tp convert the given tree (BST) into a Doubly linked list.

I am able to successfully convert the tree into a DLL. But, the problem is when I call the `destructor`.
Since, I am allocating memory to the nodes of my Tree, I also wish to free the memory.
This is the destructor of the `Tree` class ::

```
~Tree() {
        delete root;
        root = NULL;
    }
```

And this is the destructor of the `Node` class::

```
~Node() {
        delete left;
        delete right;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
```

So, the program crashes at the end!
To my understanding since the destructors that I have written kindof recursively delete all the nodes of the tree, and when the Tree is converted to a DLL, the left and right pointers indeed point to each other, so, during the call to the destructor, the destructor tries to delete the node which has already been deleted and that pointer has not been set to NULL.
How do I overcome this? Since destructor overloading is not permitted.

Is there any way I could prevent this runtime error??
This is the code :: http://ideone.com/SDkXY9
(Ideone doesn't print the output, I don't know why!)

Comment: Do you follow [the rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)? Is there a chance a node might be deleted twice? How deep is the tree?

Comment: Yes, a node is deleted twice! That is what I tried to explain in the question, `... during the call to the destructor, the destructor tries to delete the node which has already been deleted and that pointer has not been set to NULL...` The main question is that only that is there a way I can handle it anyhow?!

Comment: Do you *know* the node has been deleted before, or is it just you guessing? Can a node have multiple parents? Do you (explicitly or implicitly through a compiler generated copy-constructor or copy-assignment operator) copy a *pointer* to a node and not the node itself?

Comment: Oh, and setting a member variable to `NULL` (by the way, use `0` or `nullptr` instead) only sets *that* member variable, not any other pointer. Resetting member variables in a destructor is actually pointless, as once a destructor has been called the object (and its member variables) doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg See this: http://ideone.com/3mBqhh I have entered some print statements in the destructors, from this I conclude that the nodes are getting recursively deleted. For a normal tree, it works since there is no cycle between the nodes, but after forming DLL, there is a  cycle between every two node.

Comment: Add a flag isDestructing to the Node. Then set it before deleting left or right. In each node then check the if the left or right neighbour is having this flag set. If so, don't delete it, if not, delete it.

Comment: @user007 the name is just a hint, you can call it whatever you want ;)

Comment: If you get a loop in your tree, then you have introduced a bug somewhere in the transition. You can build debug versions of a DLL as well, and step into DLL functions in the VS debugger (which I assume you're using?). Use the debugger to step through the code, line by line until you find the error.

Comment: Have you considered using `std::unique_ptr`? The question is tagged c++11 after all

Comment: Node doesn't have to delete anything to the left, You only need to delete the right and the right will continue if right is not null

Comment: @fassl lol! something like this right??? http://ideone.com/IYF20O (Only the `Node` class)
Well this still gives a runtime error on my Netbeans IDE, but works fine on ideone. Any specific reasons?? http://ideone.com/KDYutq (Full Code)
Mindblowing idea though! :P

Comment: @nilo The code i posted here is just a small piece of what I have written, the original code has a lot of other functions as well, which are specific to a tree! So, I have to anyhow delete the `left` as well in that case.

Comment: @WorldSEnder Well, not really.. :P I'll try studying about it. :D

Comment: @user007 kind of.. remove your if statement from the destructor and do it like this: if (!left->isDestructing) delete left; if (!right->isDestructing) delete right;  got it? I think it should work

Comment: You need to check your `convertBSTtoDLLUtil` function. When you make `root` a child of another node, the previous parent node still have `root` as a child, and you get multiple parent having the same node as a child, leading to your problem.

Comment: As for why it crashes on some systems and not other, it's because of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Attempting to free the same memory more than once is undefined, and the behavior when that happens is, well, undefined and not easy to predict.

Comment: @fassl : It did.. Thanks :D Can you post it as an answer, so I can accept!?

Comment: What I don't understand is why Node's destructor is responsible for destroying anything.  What if I want to delete one Node and leave the rest alone?  Shouldn't the destructor logic go in the `Tree` destructor?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Well, I was trying to convert the same BST to a DLL, that was why there are a lot of reassignments. Well, it worked with what fassl suggested!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `leaving the rest alone` means??

Comment: @user007 Look at your design.  What if I want to delete one node and leave the rest of the Tree alone?  Is that unreasonable?  Of course not.  What good is a Tree if you can't cut branches from it?  However, your design makes that simple task impossible.  When a `Node` is deleted, the destructor destroys all the nodes connected to it.  Does that sound like a good design?  Let the `Tree` figure out what nodes to remove when it comes time to destroy itself.  All that takes is a simple recursive loop to delete the nodes.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Very well made point! I'll try modifying the destructor design.

Comment: @user007 It's really a matter of knowing how much "intelligence" a Node should have.  The Node should be created, destroyed, and linked to other Nodes by the `Tree`.  So it should be the Tree's responsibility to do the housekeeping.  By putting a destructor in Node to unlink itself from its neighbor, you have done the unthinkable -- remove a branch, and the whole tree comes tumbling down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to delete neighbours from whom the chained destruction is initiated. You will have to add a flag which you can check in the destructor for which neighbour is sane to delete.

```
~Node() {
    _isDestructing = true;
    if (!left->_isDestructing) delete left;
    if (!right->_isDestructing) delete right;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
}
```